# can i use variable content in class/function names?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

can i use variable content in class/function names?
for example:

```
string string_1 = "abcd";
double num_2 = 20.5;
int num = 1;

MessageBox.Show(string_{num}); // shows string_1;
```

[I'm newbie in Visual C# (visual studio 2008)]

Thanks.

Comment: i tried it, but i want to know is it possible or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class and method names must be constant and have to be referred to as constants in code like your example.

You can use [reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7ykdhsy.aspx) and/or the [`dynamic` type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx) for dynamic behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

No you can't. A class name is defined at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely not.

Such semantic is not possible in any programing language as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

```
double num_2 = 20.5;
MessageBox.Show(GetName(() => num_2));


public string GetName<T>(Expression<Func<T>> f)
{
    return (f.Body as MemberExpression).Member.Name;
}
```